# How to set a global variable so to keep data related to multiple jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I am using jQuery and jQuery UI, and I am almost new to JavaScript. I would like to set a global variable in the `window` object so to keep custom data related to multiple jQuery objects. That is, at this time I am using the following (poor) code:

```
// Given
window.myDataObject = {};

// Then, in the same file, I run multiple times (one time for each 'tag_id_1', 
// 'tag_id_2', ..., 'tag_id_N') the following code
var tag      = $('#tag_id_N')
myDataObject = { pagination: { page : 1, per_page: 10 } } // This aims to keep pagination data for tags.
```

Since I am trying to keep data for *multiple* `tag`s, running the above code multiple times makes the `window.myDataObject` to be continuously "re-initialized" (making the keeping process inefficient). Because that, I thought to add "namespaced" *properties* (maybe, namespaced with "something" related to each `tag` object) to `window.myDataObject` so that each `tag` has its own pagination data.

How can I make that? Is that approach a "good" / "proper" way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

> The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks.
>
> We can set several distinct values for a single element and retrieve
>   them later:

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using the `window` object not `windows`.
Secondly if you want to use multiple tags you could try to do the following:
    // Given
    windows.taggedObjects = {};

```
// Then, in the same file, I run multiple times (one time for each 'tag_id_1', 
// 'tag_id_2', ..., 'tag_id_N') the following code
var tagId = 'tag_id_N';
// This aims to keep pagination data for tags.
window.taggedObjects[tagId] = { tag: $('#' + tagId), pagination: { page : 1, per_page: 10 } };
```

To retrieve your data just use the tag id again like so:

```
alert(window.taggedObjects[tagId]);
```